# How do I change the default gmail calendar on my iphone 4?

Tags: iphone, gmail, google-calendar

I have three calendars in my gmail (one for me and my two kids). When I add an appointment on my iphone, it defaults to my son's calendar unless I manually check my calendar every single time.

Comment: what app are you adding the appointment to? The built in Calendar?

Answer (score 3):

Go to **Settings**->**Mail, Contact, Calendars**. Scroll to the **CALENDARS** section. There you will find the option: **Default Calendar**. Change that to the one you want to be default.